# Backing field for tri-state checkbox being (re)evaluated too often

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a 'naive' implementation of tri-state checkbox selection for multiple rows, a la GMail and similar apps. You can select individual rows, and there's a top-level tri-state checkbox that indicates:

1. State "All rows are checked"
2. State "Some but not all rows are checked" (intermediate)
3. State "Zero rows are checked"

I say 'naive', because the field backing that top-level checkbox is re-evaluated way too often, and I feel I need perhaps `Subject` or `Observable` fields to back it instead.

Here's a repro of my current implementation.

1. `ng new obstest --minimal` (Angular 5 CLI)
2. `cd obstest`
3. `ng generate service search` and add it to the `app.module` `providers`
4. Add this mock method to the service:

   ```javascript
   search(query: Observable<string>) {
     // Fake search, ignore query for demo
     return of<any[]>([
       { isSelected: false, id: 1, txt: 'item 1' },
       { isSelected: false, id: 2, txt: 'item 2' },
       { isSelected: false, id: 3, txt: 'item 3' },
     ]);
   }
   ```

   Normally this would use the `HttpClient` to get results from a search API endpoint.
5. Add this to the `app.component.ts` file:

   ```javascript
   enum TriState {
     NothingSelected = '[ ]',
     IntermediateSelection = '[-]',
     EverythingSelected = '[X]',
   }
   ```
6. Change the component's decoration to this:

   ```javascript
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     template: `
       <div><input (keyup)="query$.next($event.target.value)"></div>
       <div (click)="onMultiSelectChange()">{{selectionState}}</div>
       <ul *ngFor="let item of results">
         <li (click)='item.isSelected = !item.isSelected'>
           {{item.isSelected ? '[X]' : '[ ]'}} {{item.txt}}
         </li>
       </ul>`,
   })
   ```
7. Replace the component's code with this:

   ```javascript
   export class AppComponent {
     results: any[];
     query$ = new Subject<string>();

     public get selectionCount() {
       console.warn('Getting count at', new Date().toISOString());
       return this.results.filter(r => r.isSelected).length;
     }

     public get selectionState() {
       console.warn('Getting state at', new Date().toISOString());
       if (this.selectionCount === 0) { return TriState.NothingSelected; }
       if (this.selectionCount === this.results.length) { return TriState.EverythingSelected; }
       return TriState.IntermediateSelection;
     }

     constructor (service: SearchService) { 
       service.search(of('fake query')).subscribe(r => this.results = r);
     }

     onMultiSelectChange() {
       if (this.selectionState === TriState.EverythingSelected) {
         this.results.forEach(r => r.isSelected = false);
       } else {
         this.results.forEach(r => r.isSelected = true);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
8. `import` the relevant stuff in each file
9. `ng serve --open`

(Re)load the app with the console window open and:

- **Result**: *eight* warnings on the console (in my actual app this is even more), and the keep streaming in when you select/deselect items, even when observables change that have no relation/effect.
- **Expected**: *two* warnings on the console on load, two on *relevant* changes to other fields.

In KnockoutJS I knew how to do this by using "computed observables" (possibly *pure* computeds), and I'm sure this can be done with Angular 5+ (possibly with help from rxjs?). I'm just not sure how.

How would I change `selectionCount` and `selectionState` in a way that the view can data-bind to them, but they are only (re)evaluated when needed?

Can anyone enlighten me on the idiomatic Angular and/or RxJs solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.results` starts off with `null`, so it has two assignments over the lifecycle: first `null`, then the `[ ... mock data ... ]` array you provided.

Investigating your getters:

```js
  public get selectionCount() {
    console.warn('Getting count at', new Date().toISOString());
    return this.results.filter(r => r.isSelected).length;
  }

  public get selectionState() {
    console.warn('Getting state at', new Date().toISOString());
    if (this.selectionCount === 0) { return TriState.NothingSelected; }
    if (this.selectionCount === this.results.length) { return TriState.EverythingSelected; }
    return TriState.IntermediateSelection;
  }
```

When `selectionState` is called, it invokes a warning, then calls `selectionCount` twice, so three warnings are called per invocation of `selectionState`. Angular doesn't do any caching of getters. These get invoked twice over the entire lifecycle due to the two assignments of `this.results`, which accounts for six of the warnings on load. I'm not sure where the remaining two are coming from.

A more RxJS way to write this class would be to avoid the state mutations and do everything with an observable, something like:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  results$: Observable<any[]>;
  selections$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean[]>([]);
  selectionCount$: Observable<number>;
  selectionState$: Observable<TriState>;
  query$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor (service: SearchService) { 
    this.results$ = service.search(of('fake query')).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    this.selectionCount$ = combineLatest(this.results$, this.selections$).pipe(
       map(([results, selections]) => results.filter((result, i) => selections[i])),
       map(results => results.length),
    );
    this.selectionState$ = of(TriState.IntermediateSelection).pipe(concat(this.results.pipe(map(
      results => {
          if (this.selectionCount === 0) { return TriState.NothingSelected; }
          if (this.selectionCount === this.results.length) { return TriState.EverythingSelected; }
      }))));
  }

  toggle(i) {
    selections$.value[i] = !selections$.value[i];
    selections$.next(selections$.value);
  }

  toggleAll() {
    combineLatest(this.selectionState$, this.results$).pipe(
      first(),
      map(([state, results]) => {
        return results.map(() => state === TriState.EverythingSelected);
      }))
      .subscribe(this.selections$);
  }
}
```

There are probably bugs above, I didn't test it, but hopefully it conveys the idea. For the template, you'll have to use the `| async` pipe, so something like:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div><input (keyup)="query$.next($event.target.value)"></div>
    <div (click)="toggleAll()">{{selectionState | async}}</div>
    <ul *ngFor="let item of results | async">
      <li (click)='toggle($index)'>
        {{item.isSelected ? '[X]' : '[ ]'}} {{item.txt}}
      </li>
    </ul>`,
})
```

Unfortunately, Angular doesn't provide any sort of standardized state management like Redux to enforce this pattern, so you either have to be disciplined enough to do it yourself or be okay with the extra calls.

Alternatively, you could also have a wrapper component that handles the `Observable` and associated state and no template and have the child component only render the state. This would avoid all the state transforms and you'd only have to `async` the results observable. I think this is called the heavy/light component pattern? It's a pretty popular pattern to avoid having to deal with observables everywhere, however I think I got the name wrong.